# Is there an AWS service for visualizing triggers between other AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

For example say I build a workflow that uses 10 lambda functions that trigger each other and are triggered by a dynamodb table and an S3 bucket.

Is there any AWS tool that tracks how these triggers are tying together so I can easily visualize the whole workflow I’ve created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bang on, few months ago, I too was in a similar situation for my distributed architecture running on AWS.

So far, I have found the following options as possibilities. I'm still figuring out which is more suitable. But, hope this information helps you.

**1. AWS-Native option** :: Engineer your Lambda code to trigger Cloudwatch custom-metrics for any important events from within the code. Later, you may use Cloudwatch dashboard to visualize them.

**2. Non-AWS options** :: There are several of them, but all of them require you to engineer your code with their respective libraries / packages to transmit the needed information. Some of them support ASYNC invocations, so it shouldn't keep your master lambdas in the waiting state for log tracing.

[IOPipe](https://iopipe.com)
[Epsagon](https://epsagon.com)

**3. Mix of AWS & Non-AWS** :: This is a more traditional approach to our problem.  You log events to Cloudwatch Logs (like how Lambda does it out of the box), "ingest" these logs into popular log management and analysis SaaS tooling to make sense between these logs via "pattern-matching" and other proprietary techniques.

[Splunk Cloud](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/software/splunk-cloud.html)
[Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com)

All the best! Keep me posted how it is going.

cheers,
ram

Answer (score 1):

If you use CloudFormation you can visualize the resource relations with [CloudFormation Designer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/working-with-templates-cfn-designer-overview.html). However, if you don't have the resources in a CloudFormation stack, you can [create one](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/) from all the existing resources.